# Build for socketRocket failed

Tags: socketrocket

Downloaded socketRocket from GitHub, trying to build it. Getting following error - 
error: ../SocketRocket-master/Configurations/Shared/Project/Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in project "SocketRocket") (in target 'SocketRocket-iOS')

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build the project to get the socketRocket framework to include in my iOS project but you can get framework from the following link of their latest release - https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket/releases/download/0.4.2/SocketRocket.framework.zip